# Убрать jQuery из скрипта

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возникла задача искоренить jQuery из скрипта и тут же наткнулся на проблему.

Есть код:

```
function showContent(users) { 
  var data = JSON.parse($(users).closest('.user').attr('data-json')); 
}
```

В $(users) заходит объект:

[image: Содержимое объекта]

Какая есть альтернатива на чистом JavaScript для:

```
$(users).closest('.user').attr('data-json')
```

?

Comment: что такое _users_?

Comment: `function showContent(users) { var data = JSON.parse($(users).closest('.user').attr('data-json')); }`
В users заходит object

Comment: добавьте этот код в вопрос, а так же _В users заходит object_ - что за объект?

Comment: Я не знаю как по другому объяснить :)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4YdjUeWDSP8eHhIbTlNS2F6bG8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Вы можете редактировать вопрос.

Comment: Могу и редактирую) У вас есть совет для меня?

Comment: да, вы получаете праметром объект jQuery, таким образом из одной функции убрать jQuery код нельзя. надо предварительно убрать jQuery объект из параметра

Comment: Ладно, а для .closest и .attr есть альтернатива?

Comment: для `attr` - [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute), для `closest` - только свою функцию писать

Comment: Понял. Спасибо вам)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Аналогом для `attr` с одним параметром является [функция getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

Для функции `closest` аналога нет, но можно написать функцию со сходным функционалом.

Что делает функция `closest`: для каждого элемента из набора ищет первый элемент удовлетворяющий указанному правилу, начиная с самого элемента и поднимаясь вверх по иерархии DOM.

Если упростить до случая поиска элемента с классом, можно получить следующую функцию

```
function closest(element, c){
    var curElement = element;
    while(curElement && !curElement.classList.contains(c)) curElement=curElement.parentElement;

    return curElement; // вернет null если ничего не найдет
}
```

Comment: А вот что означает начало: $(users)?

Comment: @ProstoJohn, вообще это получение jQuery объекта. но так как вы и так его получаете параметром. то можно было просто `users` использовать

Comment: Вот тут выходит проблема.. Когда я пробую писать просто users получаю вот это: TypeError: users.closest(...).attr is not a function

Comment: @ProstoJohn, без знания _что именно_ передается в качестве _users_, и какие версии библиотек используются вряд ли можно что-то сказать по поводу ошибки, кроме того что `users.closest(...)` вернул объект без метода `attr`

Comment: Тут можно в лс как то писать?

Comment: @ProstoJohn, нет, но тут есть чаты, например: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34771/prostojohn

Comment: @ProstoJohn, да. в данном скрипте передается напрямую элемент, так как вызывается из инлайного обработчика _onclick_ поэтому действительно необходимо было вызывать `$(...)`

Comment: Ну вот возникла задача переработать все не используя jQuery... С append смог разобраться... а вот тут капец! Вопрос жизни и смерти! Посоветуйте что то...

Comment: Говорит что бы писать в чат нужно 20 бонусов(

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34774/discussion-between-grundy-and-prostojohn).