# Альтернатива jQuery на чистом JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я решил не использовать jQuery у себя в скрипте и у меня возникла проблема...

Есть строка на jQuery:

```
$('#info').closest('.neww')
```

Я уже нашел альтернативу для **.closest()**

Но вот как применить ее суда не могу понять.

**Альтернатива:**

```
function closestF(element, c)
{
    var curElement = element;
    while (curElement && !curElement.classList.contains(c)) curElement = curElement.parentElement;
    return curElement;
};
```

PS.

```
$('#info').closest('.neww')
```

**Вернул:**

> Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument →
>   index.html }

А вот он

```
closestF(document.getElementById('info'), 'neww')
```

**Вернул:**

> null

Comment: Angularjs как альтернатива

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich Мне вообще нельзя использовать библиотеки. Все на чистом JS.

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich не очень альтернатива если в лоб все делать, а на разбирательство уйдет больше времени чем на jquery

Comment: А кстати, в чем проблема-то? Оба варианта - не находят, просто один аналог пустого объекта возвращает, а другой напрямую Null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если посмотрите внимательно на результат работы - то увидите что они одинаковы:

```
$('#info').closest('.neww')
```

Вернул:

> Object { **length: 0**, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → index.html }

Фактически - элементов удовлетворяющих условию найдено не было

В замене - в аналогичном случае просто *null* возвращается

Answer (score 2):

Советую вам как минимум залезть в исходники `jQuery` и посмотреть как это сделано у них. Это всегда полезно смотреть исходники библиотек и фреймворков.

Еще есть классный сервис, который показывает аналоги на функции `jQuery` – http://youmightnotneedjquery.com

Comment: ОК, попробую так сделать. За сервис спасибо :-) Жаль там нет ответа на мой вопрос :-(

Comment: @ProstoJohn да, сам только заметил, что именно этой функции и нет ((

Answer (score 0):

Альтернатива `$('#info')  >  document.getElementById("info")`

Т.е. `closestF(document.getElementById('info'), '.neww')`

Comment: Кстати `$('#..` работает в среднем в 10 раз медленнее чем `document.getElementById`

Comment: `console.log($('#info').closest('.neww'))` вернул: 
`Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → index.html }`
А `console.log(closestF(document.getElementById('info'), '.neww'))` вернул:
`null`

Comment: @Darth Вот и хочу искоренить jQuery :)

Comment: @ProstoJohn [Ссылка](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com) вам в помощь в этом благом деле

Comment: Мне кажется, что у вас функция closestF написана не верно, она смотрит в parentElement, а должна смотреть вглубь выбраной ветки, т.е. хотя бы в nextSibling, а лучше в firstChild и nextSibling. Попробуйте найти  другую closestF, или написать её с ноля, допустим через рекурсию.

Comment: @nick_n_a, функция closest ищет элемент удовлетворяющий селектору начиная с текущего и поднимаясь  к предкам. При чем тут siblings?

Comment: @nick_n_a вы документацию смотрели по этой функции? Она как раз должна идти вверх по иерархии

Comment: @nick_n_a С функцией мне помогли [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485450/%D0%A3%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-jquery-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0), ну она работает ;)

Comment: @Darth Спасибо, крутая вещь ;)

Comment: @Darth, Но _closest_ там я не нашел :-)

Comment: @Grundy Угу ;-(

Comment: Нарисуй дерево елементов где не нашло, я хочу сам протестировать ф-цию.